# Trying to understand EXPLAIN results of query in mySQL

Tags: mysql, explain

Below is my EXPLAIN query and the output. I'm very much a beginner (please forgive my SQL syntax...unless that's my problem!) - can anyone explain the order of the tables here please? I've played around with the order (in the query itself) and yet the TABLE *artists* is always top in the EXPLAIN output? I gather the order relates to when the tables are accessed - if so, why *artists* first?

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT album_name, artist_name, genre_name
FROM albums
JOIN genres USING (genre_pk)
JOIN artists USING (artist_pk)
ORDER BY album_name;


| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys      | key       | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | artists | ALL    | PRIMARY            | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                    |    5 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | albums  | ref    | genre_pk,artist_pk | artist_pk | 2       | music.artists.artist_pk |    1 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | genres  | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY   | 1       | music.albums.genre_pk   |    1 | NULL                            |
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE info:

```
CREATE TABLE `artists` (
    `artist_pk` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `artist_name` varchar(57) NOT NULL,
    `artist_origin` enum('UK','US','OTHER') DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`artist_pk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `genres` (
    `genre_pk` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `genre_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`genre_pk`),
    UNIQUE KEY `genre_name` (`genre_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `albums` (
    `album_pk` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `genre_pk` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `artist_pk` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `album_name` varchar(57) NOT NULL,
    `album_year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `album_track_qty` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `album_disc_num` char(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1 of 1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`album_pk`),
    KEY `genre_pk` (`genre_pk`),
    KEY `artist_pk` (`artist_pk`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `album_name` (`album_name`),
    CONSTRAINT `albums_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`genre_pk`) REFERENCES `genres` (`genre_pk`),
    CONSTRAINT `albums_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`artist_pk`) REFERENCES `artists` (`artist_pk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: FYI, people are generally used to reading EXPLAIN PLANs in standard output format, i.e. with a `;` at the end of your query instead of a `\G`.  Can you edit your post to include that EXPLAIN PLAN output instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL explain Query understanding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999833/mysql-explain-query-understanding)

Comment: Sure thing @dg99, I did it this way as I thought it might be easier to read. We live and learn.

Comment: @simien: You better rollback to previous edit.

Comment: Sorry, novice at work. I'll get better, I promise. I don't even know how to 'up' people's reputations?! (Like you guys for being helpful).

Comment: @simien can you post please `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of all the tables?

Comment: @Max Yakimets - thanks for the editing! Do I just add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` data to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6224/2/0

As @Daniel already said, MySQL takes into account not only indices, but also the number of rows in each table. The number of rows is low both in my fiddle and in your database - so it is hard to blame MySQL.

Note that even though `STRAIGHT_JOIN` will make the order of joins seem logical to you, it will not however make the execution plan prettier (I mean `Using temporary; Using filesort` red flags)

Comment: Can you please just elaborate on what you use the fiddle for? Cheers for all your help, everyone.

Comment: The sqlfiddle is just a tool where you can share your DB schema and a query - and attach the link to your Stackoverflow question. It's comes in handy to those who read your question - they won't have to create test environment on their own MySQL installation. On sqlfiddle you can run SELECT statements against your schema and then click "View execution plan" link to see EXPLAIN output - or you can directly run EXPLAIN SELECT query.

Answer (score 2):

The order of joining your tables is depending on the SQL optimizer. The optimizer internally modifies your query to deliver results in a fast and efficient way ([read this page for more details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer.html)). To avoid internal join optimization you can use `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

In your special case, the order is depending on the number of rows in each table and the availability of indexes. Have a look at [these slides](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/21/Understanding%20and%20Control%20of%20MySQL%20Query%20Optimizer_%20Traditional%20and%20Novel%20Tools%20and%20Techniques%20Presentation.pdf) starting with page 25 for a little example.